# Difference between "это" and "этот"

Tags: грамматика, словоупотребление, разница, word

Are these two words interchangeable or is there a difference? My online dictionary says that "это" and "этот" both mean "this". I'm a bit confused.

Comment: They aren't interchangeable. The most simplified answer is that you use _это - something_ for _this/these_ + _is/was/are/were/ something_, while for _this/these something_ it becomes gender and cardinality aware _этот/эта/эти/(or again)это something_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not as simple as that.

Это can be a demonstrative adjective for a neuter noun.

(Это окно выходит в сад)

and этот for a masculine noun.

(Этот дом большой).

But introductory **it** or **this** is always **это**, no matter what comes after.

This is the house Jack built, and this is the wheat that's stored in the dark larder... What's this? This is a house.
Это дом, который построил Джек, а это пшеница, которая в темном чулане хранится...Что это?— Это дома.

Answer (score 0):

These are different inflections of the word, according to the gender of the noun it modifies: «это» mofidies neuter nouns, «этот» — masculine nouns («эта» would be feminine).

Consider using a better dictionary.